# What backer board for Kohler Choreograph in the shower - osb or greenboard?

Tags: shower, backer-board

I want to install [Kohler Choreograph](https://www.us.kohler.com/us/Choreograph-Shower-Wall-and-Accessory-Collection/article/900001.htm) sheets in my shower over tub.  It currently has a full fiberglass unit.  Should I use osb, greenboard, or possibly cement board, and do these have to be water-proofed?

Answer (score 2):

According to this video produced by Kohler, you should use greenboard or other water resistent backer material.  I wouldn't use OSB, and cement board seems like overkill but could help if you needed to stiffen up the walls I guess.

https://youtu.be/4-s-pfbj0YU

Answer (score 2):

Kohler recommends water resistant drywall or green board. Make sure you have blocking at the height needed if installing things like hand rails.

Comment: Do you have a source? I'm having trouble finding installation docs.

Comment: Found a video from kohler by searching kohler Choreograph. They stated the requirement and the need for backers, I haven't used this product so I had to look it up. I just noticed jphil 1618 posted the link I was watching we must have been there about the same time.

Comment: Would purple board be preferred over green board?

Comment: Purple is a little better because it is water resistant + mold and mildew resistant. Green is not mold and mildew resistant so yes purple would be better in a shower stall area.